# What is the correct way to document the schema for a YAML file?

Tags: 8

As a module developer, I'd like to convert some of my Drupal 7 info hooks to YAML discoveries in Drupal 8, but it's not clear to me how to document the schema of a YAML file for consumers. For a hook, of course, I would define `hook_whatever()` in `mymodule.api.php`. What do I do for `*.whatever.yml`? What is core doing?

Comment: Do you want to implement new hook exposed by other module or define new hook in your custom module ?

Comment: My custom module already invokes a hook, and I want to replace it with a YAML file. Specifically, I'm replacing [hook_shunt_info()](http://drupalcode.org/project/shunt.git/blob/refs/heads/8.x-2.x:/shunt.api.php#l13) with *.shunts.yml. I already have the feature working. My only question is: how do I document it so that module developers who used to implement my hook know how to create a YAML file instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "documenting" of hooks in D8 except the mymodule.api.php as you've already mentioned(+ impleneting hook_hook_info).

The YAML files are only for:

- services
- routes
- menu local tasks
- menu local actions
- libraries
- module info
- simple configuration
- simple configuration schema

Now you've mentioned "info" hooks. In Drupal 8 these are Annotations and their implementations are Plugins. If this is assumption correct then see the documentation in here https://drupal.org/developing/api/8/plugins for plugins - what they are, how they work and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could find to documentation of what you can and cannot put in the YAML files, are the *.schema.yml files in core. For example, when you create a new content type, the available keys for your `node.type.my_content_type.yml` file is specified in `/core/modules/node/config/schema`:

```yaml
node.type.*:
  type: config_entity
  label: 'Content type'
  mapping:
    name:
      type: label
      label: 'Name'
    type:
      type: string
      label: 'Machine-readable name'
    description:
      type: text
      label: 'Description'
    help:
      type: text
      label: 'Explanation or submission guidelines'
    new_revision:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Whether a new revision should be created by default'
    preview_mode:
      type: integer
      label: 'Preview before submitting'
    display_submitted:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Display setting for author and date Submitted by post information'
```

This means, you may specify `name`, `type`, `description`, `help`, `new_revision`, `preview_mode` and `display_submitted`. My guess is that other keys will be ignored.

This answer needs community input, since there is still a lot of uncertainty.

Comment: In my a config entity i created, other keys are not ignored, and work just fine.  So the question i found this page while looking to answer is: do we need a *.schema.yml file at all?  To whom is it useful, and is it worth the risk of it being outdated compared to the actual configuration schema in use?

Comment: One of the main use cases  for config entity `*.schema.yml` files is for [config translation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata#use)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a folder named mymodule inside sites/all/modules or modules
- Create mymodule.info.yml and mymodule.module files insides your module "mymodule" folder

Code for mymodule.info.yml goes below

```
name: My Module
description: 'My Module description.'
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

If you want to invoke a hook you need to use something like below on some event function..

```
  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('whateven', array($args));
```

For Example.. User.module does this for user logout event

```
/**
 * Logs the current user out.
 */
function user_logout() {
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();

  watchdog('user', 'Session closed for %name.', array('%name' => $user->getUsername()));

  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('user_logout', array($user));

  // Destroy the current session, and reset $user to the anonymous user.
  session_destroy();
}
```

Regarding api.php files.. They are just used for documentation purposes to help developers..

Regarding .info.yml files they are required to:

- Notify Drupal about the existence of a module, theme or install profile.
- Provide information for the Drupal Web UI administration pages.
- Provide criteria to control module activation and deactivation and Drupal version compatibility.
- General administrative purposes in other contexts.

Implementing a hook is still same in Drupal 8 .. Defining a function with module name followed by hook name.

Comment: Although this answer provides useful info on creating a new D8 module, it does not answer the question at all. The question is: How to *document* the YAML files. And: How does core *document* the YAML files that may be created by custom module developers?